# add a vertical 50% line to a ggplot2 point chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an ggplot2 point chart created like this

```
qplot(Index, Popularity ,data = data.slopeone.agg)
```

now I would like to add a vertical line at the half of all data points. In other words, where the integral is 0.5. I want add this line to see wich part of the data makes 50%.

How can I achieve this in R? I know about `geom_vline` but don't know how to determine the positon of the vline.

The data is structured like this:
Each row has an ItemId the popularity of this item and an index for my chart to display the values sorted by popularity.

```
head(data.slopeone.agg)
    Item Popularity Index
184  258 0.07695880     1
29    50 0.07294129     2
121  181 0.07162558     3
203  286 0.07030986     4
225  313 0.06500478     5
65   100 0.06366796     6
```

my chart looks like this: http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/3194/popt.png

Comment: I do not know what structure data.slopeone.agg takes. Can you include a small sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now found out how to solve my problem. Maybe it's not the most elegant way:

## define a function to get the 50% of popularity data vertical line position

```
getPopularityVLineIndex = function(popData){

  halfPopularity = sum(popData$Popularity) / 2

  # initialize helper variables
  fiftyPercent = 0;
  counter = 1;

  # sum up the popularity values until the half of the sum is reached
  while (fiftyPercent < halfPopularity) {
      fiftyPercent = fiftyPercent + popData$Popularity[which(popData$Index == counter)]
      counter = counter + 1
  }

  # the current counter value is the position of the vertical line
  vLineIndex = counter

  return (vLineIndex)
}

qplot(Index, Popularity ,data = popData) + geom_vline(xintercept = getPopularityVLineIndex(popData), colour="red", linetype = "longdash"))
```

If somebody knows a more elegant way, feel free to post it. But maybe my question is now more understandable ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
p <- qplot(data=data.slopeone.agg, x = Index, y = Popularity )
```

Now Identify the "Index" of the median Popularity value.
note that median prolly won't work if there is an even number of observations.

```
attach(data.slopeone.agg)
```

get the median Population observation

```
medpop=sort(Popularity)[floor(length(Popularity)/2)]
```

get the Index of that value

```
lineplace= Index[which(Popularity==medpop)]
detach(data.slopeone.agg)

p + geom_vline(xintercept = lineplace)
```

Comment: sorry, I corrected my answer. I think you want the median of the x variable, so `Index` in your case.

Comment: no @Seth I don't want a line at 50% of the index. I want a line at the position where the integral below the curve is 0.5. thats not the same point. take a look at the chart graphic I posted